# Nginx serves local file verse performing a proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, pki, ocsp

We are attempting to proxy OCSP responder lookups via Nginx. Clients have an OCSP lookup such as http://example.com/OCSP/EMSRootCAResponder hardcoded in their certificate which we direct to an Nginx host using our internal DNS. The Nginx host receives the same DNS responses so we must tell proxy_pass to use an external resolver so `proxy_pass` is not pointing to itself but instead, the externally hosted OCSP responder.

We are using `resolver` to try forcing Nginx to use an external DNS resolver to resolve the external OCSP service.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ocsp.example.com;
    location = / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s;
        set $domain ocsp.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://$domain;
    }
}
```

but Nginx is still trying to serve a local resource verse proxying the request to the external upstream target.

`ocsp-proxy  | 2023/12/08 16:34:32 [error] 21#21: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/OCSP/EMSSSPCAResponder" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.x.x.x, server: ocsp.example.com, request: "POST /OCSP/EMSSSPCAResponder HTTP/1.1", host: "ocsp.example.com"`

Thoughts on why Nginx is not performing `proxy_pass` but instead trying to server a local resource?

Comment: You are using `location = /` which does not match the request `POST /OCSP/EMSSSPCAResponder` - did you mean to use `location /` which matches any URL?

Comment: That worked. Please create an answer if you would like credit.